# Nested RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, richtextbox

I am creating a small custom scientific editor using RichTextBoxes. User can insert a 'formula' UserControl which itself contains one or more RichTextBoxes, allowing insert more 'formula' controls - this replicates minimal functionality of MathType.

When I insert the UserControl, it shows up alright but the RichTextBoxes are disabled within the control. Is there a way to enable the control back and allow editing within the RichTextBoxes the control contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net 3.5 solution to this is described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5372c48e-3040-4312-8263-59616e6728a8